# How to check if a certain product category is empty in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce, woocommerce

I need to check if a certain product category is empty in WooCommerce. I already know how to check if it's a certain category by using the code below, but I don't know how to check if there are any products assigned to that category.

`if ( is_product_category( 'name-of-category') {
    echo 'An example message';
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a native WooCommerce function for this, but this will get you the result you need.

The first part just gets the count of items in the current category. Then, the `if` sorts as to whether there are more than 0 items in that category while making sure we're on a product_category page.

```
    $category = get_queried_object();
    $theCount = $category->count;

    if ( ( is_product_category( 'my-product-category-slug' ) ) && ( $theCount > 0 ) ){

        echo 'Total: ' . $theCount . ' products in this category';

    } else {

        echo 'There are no products in this category';

    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, and it works perfectly! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

functions.php

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_subcategories_args', 'woocommerce_show_empty_categories');
function woocommerce_show_empty_categories($cat_args){
$cat_args['hide_empty']=0;
return $cat_args;
}
```

I hope this helps you will need to add this in your functions.php

Comment: Thanks, but I already know how to show the empty categories. What I want to do is check if a certain product category is empty and if it is, display a custom message.

Comment: can you please explain because the example code you have its a boolean and it only gives if its true or false

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it any better than what I have already written. I don't have to use the code in my example, but what I need to achieve is:

``If product category = 'x' AND if it's empty = display a custom message``

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<?php if (get_category('1')->category_count <= 0) echo "message"; ?>
```

In this example the category ID is 1.

Comment: Thanks, but when I use that code, it still shows the message even if the category has products in it, and it also displays a warning message saying "Trying to get property of non-object". Not sure what might be causing that?